# the numbering of the empty page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, blank-page

A chapter in my book ends with an odd-numbered page. The next page is an empty page with an even number.

How to remove the numbering and header on the empty page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Add to your packages also `\usepackage{emptypage}` and you'll be done. However some more information is needed, for instance the document class you're using.

Comment: You can get much more specific help, if you post an  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) along with your question. That way we can test that our suggestions work with your specific set-up or can choose the most fitting solution if several are available. It is certainly not impossible to answer your question without an MWE, but you can make sure that the answers fit your needs with an MWE.

Comment: @egreg: why not add your comment as an answer so that this question disappears from the list of unanswered questions?

Comment: @JPi I would, but the solution depends on the document class used.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the standard class `book`, then add

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

to your preamble.

Nothing at all is necessary with `scrbook` (version 3.00 or later) or `memoir`.